# Firebase JavaScript Orderby

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hi following is `JSON` structure on Cloudstore.
[image]

I want to get last 10 notification of a specific user, so I am trying the following code.

```
var collectionDocument = 'b12b9ffa-eca9-4022-b6a4-497eef873100';
console.log(collectionDocument);
var docRef = database.collection(collectionDocument + "/Notifications/");
resposne = docRef.orderBy("Timestamp").limit(3);
console.log(resposne.data());
```

It throws an error that

```
home:198 Uncaught TypeError: resposne.data is not a function
```

Am I doing it right? Or do I need to change the code? [Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#web)

Comment: Your code is using Firestore, but your screenshot shows Realtime Database.  They are different databases with different features and APIs.  You can't query RTDB from Firestore code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use async await. Append the async keyword in your function declaration inside which you are making a request. Then you need to call the `get()` method on your `response` object.

```
var docRef = database.collection(collectionDocument + "/Notifications/");
const response = docRef.orderBy("Timestamp").limit(3);
const data= await response.get();
```

Now you will be able to access the data object. Further, I think you would have to iterate over the docs property to access data regarding each individual document as shown below

```
data.docs.forEach(item=>console.log(item.data()));
```

Comment: it doesn't need to be async

Comment: You were calling the wrong method on the response object. You need to call the get() method instead of the data() method